# Exporting many excel files based on column value in pandas dataframe while maintaining formatting?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I have a dataframe that I would like to parse to individual files based on unique strings in a column "names."  I can do this with a simple function like:

```
f= lambda x: x.to_excel(os.getcwd()+'\\{}.xlsx'.format(x.name), index= False)
df.groupby('names').apply(f)
```

The caveat being that I would like write out these files with conditional formatting.  I've been able to achieve the desired formatting using ExcelWriter in the following block:

```
writer= pd.ExcelWriter('Test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter' )
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
workbook= writer.book
worksheet= writer.sheets['Sheet1']
format1= workbook.add_format({'font_color':'#ec5a24'})
format2= workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'#4b4b4b','font_color':'#ffde00'})
format3= workbook.add_format({'font_color':'#86b05b'})
worksheet.conditional_format('A2:AM10000',{'type':'formula','criteria':'=INDIRECT("E"&ROW())= "High"', 'format':format1})
worksheet.conditional_format('A2:AM10000',{'type':'formula','criteria':'=INDIRECT("E"&ROW())= "Med"', 'format':format2})
worksheet.conditional_format('A2:AM10000',{'type':'formula','criteria':'=INDIRECT("E"&ROW())= "Normal"', 'format':format3})
workbook.close()
writer.save()
```

Is there a method that would allow me to combine these two so that my output is many files (one for each unique name in the column names) which has the desired conditional formatting in the excel files?

New Code per request:

```
def new_func():
    f= lambda x: x.to_excel(os.getcwd()+'\\{}.xlsx'.format(x.name), index= False)
    writer= pd.ExcelWriter(x.name, engine='xlsxwriter' )
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
    workbook= writer.book
    worksheet= writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    format1= workbook.add_format({'font_color':'#ec5a24'})
    format2= workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'#4b4b4b','font_color':'#ffde00'})
    format3= workbook.add_format({'font_color':'#86b05b'})
    worksheet.conditional_format('A2:AM10000',{'type':'formula','criteria':'=INDIRECT("E"&ROW())= "High"', 'format':format1})
    worksheet.conditional_format('A2:AM10000',{'type':'formula','criteria':'=INDIRECT("E"&ROW())= "Med"', 'format':format2})
    worksheet.conditional_format('A2:AM10000',{'type':'formula','criteria':'=INDIRECT("E"&ROW())= "Low"', 'format':format3})
    workbook.close()
    writer.save()
df.groupby('names').apply(new_func())
```

Comment: you could wrap your lambda function and all those formatting lines into one function and call that instead of f. replace 'Test.xlsx' with x.name and it should all work once you define your new function

Comment: I would like to clarify something with you.  what I've done is to create a function like 'def new_func():
    f= lambda x: x.to_excel(os.getcwd()+'\\{}.xlsx'.format(x.name), index= False)
    writer= pd.ExcelWriter(x.name, engine='xlsxwriter' ) ` Then all that followed by the formating.  Then I call new_func() on `df.groupby('names').apply(new_func())` I'm getting NameError: name 'x' is not defined.  I'm really new to this, sorry for bugging you.

Comment: update your original question please. add your new code after the rewrite and i'll take a look. It's hard to read the code in the comment. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for me (I added a header format too), using a lot of help from johathan:

```
def new_func(x):
        writer= pd.ExcelWriter(os.getcwd()+'\\{}.xlsx'.format(x.name), engine='xlsxwriter' )
        x.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
        workbook= writer.book
        worksheet= writer.sheets['Sheet1']
        format1= workbook.add_format({'font_color':'#ec5a24'})
        format2= workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'#4b4b4b','font_color':'#ffde00'})
        format3= workbook.add_format({'font_color':'#86b05b'})
        header= workbook.add_format({'font_size':14, 'bold': True, 'font_color':'#3582c0'})
        worksheet.conditional_format('A2:AM10000',{'type':'formula','criteria':'=INDIRECT("E"&ROW())= "High"', 'format':format1})
        worksheet.conditional_format('A2:AM10000',{'type':'formula','criteria':'=INDIRECT("E"&ROW())= "Med"', 'format':format2})
        worksheet.conditional_format('A2:AM10000',{'type':'formula','criteria':'=INDIRECT("E"&ROW())= "Low"', 'format':format3})
        pandas.io.formats.excel.ExcelFormatter.header_style = None
        worksheet.set_row(0, None, header)
        workbook.close()
        writer.save()
    
       
df.groupby('name').apply(new_func)
```

Answer (score 0):

A few edits to your code. It may take a bit of debugging to get it right. hard to tell as I don't have the data to test with. but i think you are on the right track

```
def new_func(x): # add x as and object to be passed to the function
    # remove f= lambda x: from line below. you aren't calling a lambda function any longer
    x.to_excel(os.getcwd()+'\\{}.xlsx'.format(x.name), index= False)
    writer= pd.ExcelWriter(x.name, engine='xlsxwriter' )
    # the df below should be x, I think???
    x.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
    workbook= writer.book
    worksheet= writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    format1= workbook.add_format({'font_color':'#ec5a24'})
    format2= workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'#4b4b4b','font_color':'#ffde00'})
    format3= workbook.add_format({'font_color':'#86b05b'})
    worksheet.conditional_format('A2:AM10000',{'type':'formula','criteria':'=INDIRECT("E"&ROW())= "High"', 'format':format1})
    worksheet.conditional_format('A2:AM10000',{'type':'formula','criteria':'=INDIRECT("E"&ROW())= "Med"', 'format':format2})
    worksheet.conditional_format('A2:AM10000',{'type':'formula','criteria':'=INDIRECT("E"&ROW())= "Low"', 'format':format3})
    workbook.close()
    writer.save()
df.groupby('names').apply(new_func) #removed () after new_func. I don't think you need it with the current syntax
```

Comment: I'm getting two sets of files here for the same name.  One is has no ending and one is an xlsx (without the formatting). I'm guessing the xlsx are coming when new_func is applied and runs the first line of the function "x.to_excel..."  Just need to get the formatting to apply to the xlsx.  The files without an extension when opened in chrome have folders and xml docs inside.  Again, thank you for your help!